# if elseif in variable group Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I have the following code insde the yml file and unfortunately in does not go in each condition:

variables:

```
  ${{ if eq(parameters.SOMETHING2, 'true') }}:
    VARNAME: 'PATH'
  ${{ elseif and( eq(parameters.SOMETHING2, 'false'), eq(parameters.PARAM, 'value') ) }}:
    VARNAME: 'PATH'
  ${{ elseif and( eq(parameters.SOMETHING2, 'false'), eq(parameters.PARAM, 'value') ) }}:
    VARNAME: 'PATH'
```

The last block of if elseif does not work as in if I select parameters.SOMETHING2 it will not echo the VARNAME.

Comment: Hi vPilu. Can you provide a bit more detail? It looks like all branches of your conditional expression are setting the same value. Also, the last two conditions are identical. It would help if you format the code you paste in so it's easier to read. Given what you've posted you need to select both the SOMETHING2 **and** PARAM parameters for the last two `elseif` blocks to evaluate.

Comment: Solved eventually. It was runtimeparameters value interpretation from my side.